My Python 3.11 did not use new error message
I'm using Python 3.10 for my daily driver because of some dependency. Now, I just download Python 3.11, install it, and successfully use environment.
(env311) PS D:\user\package> py
Python 3.11.6 (tags/v3.11.6:8b6ee5b, Oct  2 2023, 14:57:12) [MSC v.1935 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

I install it because I want to utilize the new error message pointer. But, why is this that I got?
>>> import itertools
>>> 
>>> c = itertools.counter()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'itertools' has no attribute 'counter'. Did you mean: 'count'?

It didn't produce better error message claimed at this and this like this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "util.py", line 3, in <module>
    c = itertools.counter()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'itertools' has no attribute 'counter'. Did you mean: 'count'?


EDIT 1
Thanks for the answer. If by chance any of you know how to enable it on jupyter notebook or other mode, greatly appreciated. For now, I can port my notebooks to scripts.

@Guy no, the message error in article contains ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^, but not on my case.

You won't see the carets if you run in IDLE which is what you seem to be doing. Run a script (.py) to see the expected output

@SIGHUP thanks, someone just answer that. But, is there anyway to make it available on other mode such as jupyter notebook?

I don't think it's available with Jupyter. You could file an issue with them, to see if they're willing to implement it.

You're in interactive mode. The functionality you're looking for only works when a source file is available. It doesn't work for statements typed in interactively.
Try this:
# in foo.py

import itertools
c = itertools.counter()

And run using py foo.py,
py foo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\user\foo.py", line 2, in <module>
    c = itertools.counter()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'itertools' has no attribute 'counter'. Did you mean: 'count'?


Thanks, testing foo.py and it is indeed works. Any chance to make it works in other mode, such as jupyter notebook file?

@MuhammadYasirroni: For a notebook? Notebooks use IPython traceback handling rather than the default logic, and that traceback format makes it kind of awkward to insert the ^^^^^ pointers. I don't know if there are any plans to change how IPython handles this.
